# Adding text obtained from a web service to a grid view

Tags: android, xml, web-services, android-layout, gridview

I am developing an app in which I am defining a grid view in my layout. I am not giving any background images. I am just giving a background color.
The data which I want to add I am obtaining from a **webservice**. If the data is little big it has to get adjusted in a grid field automatically.But when I add data its not getting added. It is just showing as a single line in my relative layout.
I am new to android. Kindly help me.

this is the method which gets data from the webservice and adds to the grid.

```
private void callService()
    {           
        ArrayList<String> devices;
        devices=new ArrayList<String>();
        ODataConsumer con=ODataJerseyConsumer.create("url of the webservice");
        List<OEntity> listEntities = con.getEntities("Devices").execute().toList();
        if (listEntities.size() > 0)
           {

                       for (OEntity entity : listEntities)
                       {

                           devices.add(entity.getProperty("Name").getValue().toString()+ " - "

                                   + entity.getProperty("AliasName").getValue()

                                           .toString());
                       }

             }
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,devices );
         grid.setAdapter(adapter);

     }
```

Can anyone please help me with this.. I am new to android so I might have done silly mistakes.

This is my xml layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/arcontroller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/tabledisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_centerInParent ="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="@color/peach"

    >
</GridView>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/page4" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Page4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="page4ButtonClick" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/page3" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Page3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/page4"
    android:onClick="page3ButtonClick" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/page2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Page2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/page3" 
    android:onClick="page2ButtonClick"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/page1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Page1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/page2"
    android:onClick="page1ButtonClick" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what your problem.

Comment: Whatever method i have done above is this the correct way to insert data into a grid view?.. I just want to insert some data into a grid view. But that data i am obtaining from a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add or set items to your adapter.

I suspect you are calling your `callService` method from a thread other than UI thread since you say you are getting data from a web service. If that's the case, you should call `notifyDataSetChanged` on UI thread. This can help:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried..no change..is my layout correct and whatever i am writing to get data from webservice is it correct?..

Comment: I don't see any problem.